# Kyoto2006+ Dataset or other label network/host security datasets

Tags: security, machine-learning, intrusion-detection

Does anyone know how to access the Kyoto2006+ data set or another labeled security dataset?  An email to the Japanese authors of the set has not been returned. The DARPA and KDD sets are outdated.

If anyone else is interested, here is the running list of some sets:

-UNB ISCX 2012 Intrusion Detection Evaluation Dataset

-iCTF (unlabeled)

-DEFCON (unlabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's kyoto 2006+ url that email by Japanese authors to me one years ago:

http://www.takakura.com/Kyoto_data/

Comment: Have you done some experiments over it? May I get any Repo or reference\paper you find useful about the nature of this data?